# Convert file.modificationDate to UNIX? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, time, air, flash-builder

On my Flex project, when I call a `File`'s `modificationDate` property, it's being displayed as `Wed Mar 7 20:14:07 GMT+0800 2012`. Can anyone help me out on how to convert that to a UNIX timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Date` class

```
( new Date( "Wed Mar 7 20:14:07 GMT+0800 2012" ) ).time
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time

but you should be able just access the `time` property of the file's `modificationDate` (assuming it is a `Date` object)

Comment: Thank you! I can't accept this answer just yet. StackOerflow requires that I wait 7 minutes more. :P But that did the trick!